Finding a way to run tests using @tagID in webdriverIO
`I have implemented Mobile-Automation in WebdriverIO with playwright & Appium
Currently i am facing an issue with run tests using single @tag, currently what happening is, all scripts are running but suppose i have to execute only specific script-tag so is there any way to do so.
Using:
WebdriverIO
Appium
What i tried is added tag script into package.json as new script & tried to run this below command to run tests containing @tagID. Currently i have to comment other tests if i want to run single or multiple selected tests.
npm run tag --t "@tagID"
Package.json:
`"scripts": {
"wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.js",
"tag": "npm run wdio -- -t"
}``
